# error after calling simple getter method: basic_string::_S_create

Tags: c++, string, pointers, runtime-error, getter

I have a simple function that prints out the name of a person using a getter method. It prints out the name fine the first time but the second time it throws an error and stops working.

The debugger shows that the value of the persons name changes from what it was supposed to be to a jumble of random letters and numbers after the initial call is made.

Any help would be much appreciated.

`error basic_string::_S_create`

```
string personName("Jim");

// check if person already exists (will return NULL in
// the case of Jim during this test)
Person *person = personList.getPerson(personName);

if(!person)
{
    cout << "creating new person" << endl;
    person = createPerson(personName);
    cout << person->getName() << endl; // prints 'Jim'
    cout << person->getName() << endl; // stops working here.
}

Person* createPerson(string name)
{
    Person person(name);
    personList.addPerson(person);
    Person *foundPerson = personList.getPerson(name);
    return foundPerson;
}
```

PersonList

```
...

void PersonList::addPerson(Person& person)
{
    Person *person_ptr = &person;
    personList.push_back(person_ptr);
}

Person* PersonList::getPerson(string name)
{
    for(vector<Person*>::iterator it = personList.begin(); it != personList.end(); ++it)
    {
        if((*it)->getName() == name)
        {
            return *it;
        }
    }
}

...
```

Person

```
class Person
{
public: 
    Person(string _name)
    string getName() const;
    ...
private:
    string name;
    ...
}

...

Person::Person(string _name)
:name(_name)
{
}

string Person::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

...
```

Comment: Show the smallest code you can come up with that compiles, runs, and shows the problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks. I'll give that a go. I have also shown the getPerson function which contains an iterator. I wonder if that's why it keeps changing.

Comment: Not a solution, but I notice that the comparison in the for loop in getPerson() is wrong. You should be using it!=personList.end() instead of it!=personList.begin().

Comment: Also, getPerson() needs to return 0 if the lookup fails. Your compiler should have warned you about that. Could we see createPerson, please? I suspect you're pushing a dangling pointer into the PersonList.

Comment: @HariMahadevan thanks. that was just a typo though.

Comment: Again not a solution, but couple of tips: In the Person ctor, it's better to pass the name parameter as a const reference. This will avoid needless copying of the object during the call. Not a big deal for a small string object, but for sizeable objects it can make a difference. Anyway it's a good practice to develop early. Similarly, getName() can return a const reference to the name member rather than duplicating it.

Comment: @HariMahadevan Thanks for the tips - i'll give them a go. I've added the createPerson function.

Comment: @RobotEyes Can you please just post your full code? It is difficult to diagnose the problem from just snippets.

Comment: @remyabel thanks. there's a lot of code so i'm not sure it will all fit here. I think i'll try and condense the problem first.

Comment: In addPerson, you add a pointer to a Person to the vector. I'm guessing that you do not use `new Person` to create that pointer; instead, you use & on some local variable, possibly the argument. That's a dangling pointer because the lifetime of the object it points to will end right away but the pointer continues to live on.

Comment: @rici thanks. You might be on to something there. I've added the addPerson function. How would I add the pointer to the vector using the new keyword?

Comment: @rici yep. that's solved it nicely. thanks again. So I use new when I want to create an object that lives beyond the end of scope?

Answer (score 0):

change your add person to:

```
void PersonList::addPerson(Person& person)
{
    Person *person_ptr = new Person(person);
    personList.push_back(person_ptr);
}
```